# Erasing Value on Click in aura component

Tags: aura, html

I'd like to know if there's is any tag in within aura components markup, that deletes the current value upon click.

[image: Field Example]

In the above image, the user will click on the last two fields, and fill them with the current value of the product. In the moment the user clicks on the field with the $14,56 value, it should disappear without the user hitting backspace or delete keys on the keyboard.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an onclick handler. Here's a demo you can copy-paste.

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />
    <lightning:input type="currency" label="Demo" onclick="{!c.clear}" aura:id="demo" />    
</aura:application>
```

---

```
({
    init: function(c, e, h) {
        c.find("demo").set("v.value", 14.56);
    },
    clear: function(c, e, h) {
        c.find("demo").set("v.value", null);
    }
})
```